# convert a list in rows of dataframe in one column to simple string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has list in one column that I want to convert into a simple string

```
    id          data_words_nostops
    26561364    [andrographolide, major, labdane, diterpenoid]
    26561979    [dgat, plays, critical, role, hepatic, triglyc]
    26562217    [despite, success, imatinib, inhibiting, bcr]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
id          data_words_nostops
26561364    andrographolide, major, labdane, diterpenoid
26561979    dgat, plays, critical, role, hepatic, triglyc
26562217    despite, success, imatinib, inhibiting, bcr
```

Comment: can you add some of your code in [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```py
df['data_words_nostops'] = df['data_words_nostops'].apply(lambda row : ','.join(row))
```

Complete code :

```py
import pandas as pd
l1 = ['26561364', '26561979', '26562217']
l2 = [['andrographolide', 'major', 'labdane', 'diterpenoid'],['dgat', 'plays', 'critical', 'role', 'hepatic', 'triglyc'],['despite', 'success', 'imatinib', 'inhibiting', 'bcr']]


df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1, l2)), 
               columns =['id', 'data_words_nostops'])
df['data_words_nostops'] = df['data_words_nostops'].apply(lambda row : ','.join(row))
```

**Output :**

```
id  data_words_nostops
0   26561364    andrographolide,major,labdane,diterpenoid
1   26561979    dgat,plays,critical,role,hepatic,triglyc
2   26562217    despite,success,imatinib,inhibiting,bcr
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["data_words_nostops"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["data_words_nostops"][0], axis=1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just return the first value of the list inside of `data_words_nostops`?

Comment: I think list contains only one element and it is whole string. If it is different than this, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas [str join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for this:

```
df["data_words_nostops"] = df["data_words_nostops"].str.join(",")

df

      id           data_words_nostops
0   26561364    andrographolide,major,labdane,diterpenoid
1   26561979    dgat,plays,critical,role,hepatic,triglyc
2   26562217    despite,success,imatinib,inhibiting,bcr
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following as well

```
df_ready['data_words_nostops_Joined'] = df_ready.data_words_nostops.apply(', '.join)
```